# Code to remove everything to the right of a char givess error

Tags: vba, excel

I am tiring to remove everything including the `.` to the right of the `.` e.g `aaaaa.ntuthuh` I get `aaaaa`

If I paste `= Left(A1, Find(".", A1) - 1)` in a cell in the worksheet the formula works fine but in a macro I get the error`Sub or Function not defined` and the `Find` is highlighted

Thanks

```
Sub Split()
    Dim fName As String

    fName = Left(A1, Find(".", A1) - 1)
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = fName

    ' have also tyred: Range("A1").Value = "=Left(A1, Find(".", A1) - 1)"  and: Range("A2").Formula = "=Left(A1, Find(".", A1) - 1)" but throws error "." is highlighted a "Expected end of statement"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two options for you:

1) use `.Formula` property

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("B1")
    .Formula = "=Left(A1, Find(""."", A1) - 1)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

2) use `Evaluate`:

```
fName = Evaluate("Left(A1, Find(""."", A1) - 1)")
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = fName
```

both will give you the same result

Answer (score 2):

And here is a third option:

```
Sub Splitt()
    Dim fName As String
    fName = Split(Range("A1").Value, ".")(0)
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = fName
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Gary's Student

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work, with one minor change.  Before, you had in a value of A1 for the Left and Find functions, when you should be supplying the range to calculate.  Note that this may cause errors if there is no "." in the input string.

```
Sub Split()
    Dim fName As String

    fName = Left(activesheet.Range("A1"), Find(".", ActiveSheet.Range("A1")) - 1)
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = fName
End Sub
```

However, a different solution would be to create a function that allows you to specify the range you want stripped, and to output the result.  So, in cell B1, you would put "=Splitter(A1)"

```
    Function Splitter(range As range) As String
        Dim fName As String
        If InStr(range.Value, (".")) = 0 Then
            Splitter = range.Value
        Else
            fName = Left(range.Value, InStr(range.Value, ".") - 1)
            Splitter = fName
        End If
    End Function
```